# Numpy array subtraction: inconsistent values for large arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

Here's a problem I came across today: I am trying to subtract the first row of a matrix from the (large) entire matrix. As a test, I made all rows equal. Here's a MWE:

```
import numpy as np
first = np.random.normal(size=10)
reference = np.repeat((first,), 10000, axis=0)
copy_a = np.copy(reference)
copy_a -= copy_a[0]
print np.all(copy_a == 0) # prints False
```

Oh wow - `False`! So I tried another thing:

```
copy_b = np.copy(reference)
copy_b -= reference[0]
np.all(copy_b == 0) # prints True
```

Examining the new `copy_a` array, I found that `copy_a[0:818]` are all zeros, `copy_a[820:]` are the original values, while `copy_a[819]` got operated partly.

```
In [115]: copy_a[819]
Out[115]: 
array([ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.57704706, -0.22270692, -1.83793342,
        0.58976187, -0.71014837,  1.80517635, -0.98758385, -0.65062774])
```

Looks like midway during the operation, `numpy` went back and looked at `copy_a[0]`, found it is all zeros, and hence subtracted zeros from the rest of the array. I find this weird. Is this a bug, or is it an expected `numpy` result?

Comment: The number of elements for which `-=` worked correctly in your example is 8192, which is exactly 2^13!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue has actually been reported multiple times to the numpy repository (see below). **[It is considered a bug](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6119#issuecomment-125334416)**, but is very hard to fix without sacrificing performance (copying the input arrays) because correctly detecting if two arrays share memory is difficult.

Therefore, for now, you'd better just make a copy of `copy_a[0]` as explained in [@Torben's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40968484/224671).

The essence of the issue is that your are modifying the array while iterating. It happens to work until `copy_a[819]` simply because 8192 (819×10+2) is the [size of numpy's assign buffer](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/6587f66b57daf10f17ebba8b759d98542e38077d/numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign.h#L71).

---

1. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/6119
2. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5241
3. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/4802
4. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2705
5. https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/1683

Answer (score 3):

The infix operator `-=` modifies the array inplace, meaning that you are pulling the rug under your own feet. The effect that you see might have to do with internal caching of results (i.e. first "commit" happens after 818 rows).

The solution is to swap out the subtrahend into another array:

```
copy_a -= copy_a[0].copy()
```

Comment: Nice. Seems to match up with the 2^13 pointed out by @DYZ above. But doesn't this seem like a bad idea? It is the inconsistency that bothers me. I'd expect this to either give all zeros, or give up right after the first row (strict inplace). In the current implementation, it seems like the final answer will depend on the cache size.

Comment: @VBB: I think the idea is just that self-referential in-place operations have undefined behavior.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Generally, when you work with large arrays you need to have a clear picture of the underlying memory allocations, or else your RAM will be gone quickly. :-)